# Add characters to intellij's reservoir

Tags: intellij-idea, character

As you probably know, Intellij doesn't recognize all the different characters in the world. How would I configure Intellij IDEA so that it would not translate § into an unknown character box thing?

I have looked for a solution, but nothing has arisen. The reason I need that character is because the API I am using requires that character to do something with strings.

Comment: Is it possible that character isn't in the font that the IntelliJ IDEA editor uses?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.